# Display the current value on a range slider with simple_form and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-6, bootstrap-5

i look for a solution to display the current value on a simple_form range

```
  <%= f.input :data, as: :range, prompt: "my data", collection: 0..45 %>
```

i find nothing on the documentation.

https://simple-form-bootstrap.herokuapp.com/documentation
https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/blob/86429bceb950096df3c29616f31bd5a5ce706c06/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution with a tiny javascript code.

```
<%= f.input :data, as: :range, input_html:{ min:"0", max:"45", oninput:"updateTextInput(this.value)"}%>
 <input type="text" id="textInput" value="">


<script>
function updateTextInput(val) {
          document.getElementById('textInput').value=val;
        }
</script>
```

It exist an external library for custom slider but it don't work on my app, bootstrap 5
http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/